# What is Multimode Delay Distortion?

Tags: wire, optics

I understand that the data has been distorted through the multimode fiber but is this due to a bandwidth that is longer than what the fiber can handle?  What causes the distortion and how is it dealt with?

Comment: Where did you read about this? Can you quote the exact language used?

Comment: Does the Wikipedia article [Modal dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_dispersion) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Each symbol you send down the fiber is represented by a number of photons.  Some of them take a fairly quick path through the fiber, while others bounce around a bit, so they don't all arrive after the same delay.  As a result, the symbol becomes "smeared" around in time.  It's the same phenomenon as multipath distortion in radio applications, but on a different scale.